# Empty input field before deleting w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a page where I append a delete icon to certain form text fields:

```
$(this).parent().append(\'<span class="remove" onclick="$(this).parent().remove(); return false"><span class="delete"></span></span>\');
```

and I get

```
<div>
    <input type="text"><span class="remove" onclick="$(this).parent().remove(); return false"><span class="delete"></span></span>
</div>
```

It works fine, but when I submit the form the fields that I "delete" still post information. I think they are still in DOM, just don't show. However, if I manually clear input field and then submit -- data is not posted, obviously. How do i empty text field before remove()?

Comment: Why the two spans (remove and delete)? Also, have you tried using .empty() instead or .remove()?

Comment: `$(this).parent().find('input').val('').end().remove();`

Comment: simplest solution is don't use an input for the "button".. can be any tag you want that isn't a form element

Comment: Why are you suing SPANs instead of the semantically-correct A-tag?

Comment: @Diodeus sends me to the top of the page. All i need is something to register a click.

Comment: @santa As per charlieftl, you could use an element like, say... button (if it's a button). Or if you use an anchor (as per Diodeus) you just need to return false or preventDefault in the click handler so that there's no page jump. Finally, you shouldn't be using onclick. You're already using jQuery, so use `.on()` to bind a click event.

Comment: @santa..your span parent is an inpt, no reason for that element

Comment: @j08691 tried empty() -- same results

Comment: @Greg Pettit  I append that delete icon to the form fields, only a few. I suppose I could give it a custom class name and add a "real" jQuery code to my header, calling the action what the class is clicked?..

Comment: return false from click handler on A-tag, won't go to top

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would empty inputs by [setting their values](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to the empty string:

```
$('input:text').val('')
```

Answer (score 0):

When a form submit some request, only inputs that has attribute "name" set will be sent.

So, if you do `$(this).before().removeAttr('name'); $(this).parent().remove();` the input content will not be sent..

But, if the input is a form child, when it is removed through jQuery.remove, it is not sent in a future form request, like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MPf67/1/) shows

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.val()` use `.attr('value', '')` and make the field Disabled to prevent any submission on that field. Try this one:

```
$(this).parent().find('input:text').attr({value: '', disabled : true}).remove();
```